# ProcessBuilder engenders a critical Sonar vulnerability

Tags: java, sonarqube, processbuilder

I am trying to execute a cmd command on Java using ProcessBuilder. This is the code I am using:

```
        ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", scriptPath, pathDirectory, fileName);
    Process process = processBuilder.start();
```

However sonar analysis produced the following error:

[image]

How to fix this error?

Comment: If https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/type/Vulnerability/RSPEC-2076 is to be believed, you can scan `scriptPath` for backslashes, and refuse to execute the command if it contains any.

Answer (score 0):

I confirm you should trust the description of [RSPEC-2076](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/type/Vulnerability/RSPEC-2076) and you should sanitize the variables that can be tainted by a user input. It can be one of your three variables: scriptPath, pathDirectory, fileName. Recent versions of SonarQube show which variable can be tainted by a user and must be sanitized. One way to sanitize is to check if the command that will be executed is part of a white list and to stop the processing if you detect a suspicious, unexpected command.

See also https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/java/IDS07-J.+Sanitize+untrusted+data+passed+to+the+Runtime.exec%28%29+method for more details.